# How to add a Clear Button on a Formik Textfield

Tags: reactjs, ref, formik

I want to add a Clear Button as a convenience to users:

```
constructor(props) {
    this.emailInput = React.createRef();
}

<Field label="Email" name="email" ref={this.emailInput} onChange={onChange} component={TextField}/>
```

But get this:

`Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail.`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To reset particular fields, use `setFieldValue` to set value to an empty string.

> **`setFieldValue: (field: string, value: any, shouldValidate?: boolean) => void`**
>
> Set the value of a field imperatively. `field` should match the key of `values` you wish to update. Useful for creating custom input change handlers.
>
> - [Formik Documentation](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean-void)

*Eg:*

```html
<Formik 
  initialValues={initialValues}
  ...
>
    {({ setFieldValue }) =>
        ...
        <button type="reset" onClick={() => setFieldValue('fieldName', '')}>
            Reset This
        </button>
        ...
```

To reset all fields, use `resetForm`.

> **`resetForm: (nextValues?: Values) => void`**
>
> Imperatively reset the form. This will clear `errors` and `touched`, set `isSubmitting` to `false`, `isValidating` to `false`, and rerun `mapPropsToValues` with the current WrappedComponent's props or what's passed as an argument.
>
> - [Formik Documentation](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#resetform-nextvalues-values-void)

*Eg:*

```html
<Formik 
  initialValues={initialValues}
  ...
>
    {({ resetForm }) =>
        ...
        <button type="reset" onClick={resetForm}>
            Reset All
        </button>
        ...
```

Codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/7122xmovnq

Answer (score 3):

Formik has a built in method called [resetForm](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#resetform-nextvalues-values-void) which can be accessed like the other formik methods. In your form you probably have something like

```
<Formik 
  initialValues={something}
  validationSchem={someSchema}
  render={() => {
    ...some form stuff
    }
  }

/>
```

you can access the formik props inside that render method and do what you want with them:

```
<Formik 
  initialValues={something}
  validationSchem={someSchema}
  render={(props) => {
    ...some form stuff
    <button type="button" onClick={() => props.resetForm()}>reset form</button>
    }
  }

/>
```

Comment: thanks but seeking a user entered text clearing X button on each Textfield.

Comment: in that case you can use the `setFieldValue` function with the name of your field

Answer (score 2):

you can try to set a reset button in your form, e.g

```
<form>
 <Field label="Email" name="email" onChange={onChange} component={TextField}/>
 <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

I took the example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/reset), it has to reset all of the inputs in the form

Comment: @Maksym this is not gonna reset Formik form.